# Javascript change text in parent from iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, parent

I have the following variable in a script in a webpage :

```
var isRedirect = true;
```

I also have an iframe. How can I change the `isredirect` value from true to false from within the iframe? `var isRedirect = true;` is in the parent page.

Comment: What do you mean by from within the iframe? Do you want to change the value manually?

Comment: Try this `parent.isRedirect  = false;` from `iframe`.

Comment: I need a javascript code in my iframe to change the variable`s isredirect value that is located in my main page

Comment: You got it, check the comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
parent.isRedirect = false;
```

The tricky part is to have the correct synchronization between the parent and the iframe. To make sure the variable already exists in the parent, you can do this:

```
if (parent.isRedirect) {parent.isRedirect = false;}
```

Comment: It is not working. The script in the main page rewrites itself. IS there a way to change only the first occurrence of a string that is located in the main page from the iframe?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand (and maybe you need to add more details in your question). What do you mean by "the script rewrites itself" and "the first occurrence of a string"?

Comment: I need to change the first occurrence of the string true with false. I have a button on the main page that when it is clicked there is a script that rewrites the entire page code. All I need now is to change the first occurrence of the string true with false

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
parent.isRedirect = true;
```

Comment: It is not working. The script in the main page rewrites itself. IS there a way to change only the first occurrence of a string that is located in the main page from the iframe?

Comment: You say that the script rewrites itself. What do you mean by this? Can you post some more code?

Comment: I need to change the first occurrence of the string true with false. I have a button on the main page that when it is clicked there is a script that rewrites the entire page code. All I need now is to change the first occurrence of the string true with false

Comment: If you use `myString.replace(/true/, "false");` it should just take the first instance.